# Control axis label size when plotting igraph object in R

Tags: r, plot, visualization, igraph

Is there any possibility to control for the font size of axis labels when plotting a network generated with igraph in R?
Contrary to the package "network", cex.lab doesn't change anything when passed to 'plot'.

An example:

```
library(igraph)

testnet <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(diag(10))

plot(testnet,xlab="This is xlab Text")

par(mfrow=c(2,3))

replicate(6,plot(testnet,xlab="This is xlab Text"))      

replicate(6,plot(testnet,xlab="This is xlab Text",cex.lab=10))
```

With multiple plots on one page, the default font size is too small.

Note that I am not talking about setting the size of vertex labels (vertex.label.cex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option: add the label size to `par`.

One size for all plots

```
rr <- 2; cc <- 3
par(mfrow=c(rr,cc), cex.lab=1.5)
replicate(6,plot(testnet,xlab="This is xlab Text"))
```

Different sizes for the plots:

```
par(mfrow = c(rr,cc))
plot.new()
cex.labs <- matrix(runif(2*3, 1, 3), ncol=cc, nrow=rr)
for (x in seq_len(rr))
  for (y in seq_len(cc)) {
    par(mfg=c(x,y), cex.lab = cex.labs[x,y])
    plot(testnet,xlab="This is xlab Text") 
  }
```

Comment: thank you! adding the label size to `par` works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround to your problem (even if it is not the solution to it). One possibility to get what you want is to omit the x-label and add a customizable text below your plot.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

# plot with x-axis label
plot(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(diag(10)), xlab = "mylab")

# plot w/o x-axis label + text
plot(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(diag(10)))
text(0, -1.8, labels = "myxlab", cex = 2.5)
```

This could be your result.
[image]

Comment: thank you, that's a good workaround, but the accepted answer solves the problem directly.